# pandas dataframe: remove all rows that includes in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe like below:

dataframe 1 (name: df)

[image]

as you can see: each (A,B,C) has n X's and V's

and I made outlier df as

```
df_outlier = df[(df["V"] > 150)]
```

Then, I want to remove all (A,B,C) that includes in df_outlier

for example, if df_outlier looks like below:

[image]

I want to remove below rows from original dataframe:
[image]

First, I tried below codes:

```
df_filtered = pd.merge(df, df_outlier, indicator=True, how = 'outer').query('_merge=="left_only"').drop(['_merge'],axis=1)
```

However, it only remove rows in df_outlier, not all (a,b,c) rows in df_outlier

Sorry for my poor English skills, so if you fell harder to understand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the column in df_outlier for check

```
df_filtered = pd.merge(df, df_outlier[['A','B','C']], indicator=True, how = 'outer').query('_merge=="left_only"').drop(['_merge'],axis=1)
```

Comment: Great answer, question for you @BENY I've read that query() is bad for performance, would you recommend this for a larger df?

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn `df_filtered = pd.merge(df, df_outlier[['A','B','C']], indicator=True, how = 'outer').loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=="left_only"].drop(['_merge'],axis=1)`

Comment: @BENY Ok so in a larger df you would recommend using a lambda instead? Thank you, I have a very similar situation like this in work, and I'll probably using something like this

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn if the data is large, you may want to check combine the multiple column into one as unique key ~ , then we could use isin~